Why is there a 20MB chunks folder when I switch my Astro site to the Cloudflare adapter?
I have a very small Astro site with 1 page that should be rendered on the server, so I switched my static site over to SSR with the Cloudflare adapter, but this caused an almost 20MB folder to appear at dist -> _workers.js -> chunks. This causes my website to be well over the 3MB limit for workers / pages projects on Cloudflare Workers free tier. Without this folder, my site is only about 450 KB, so I'm wondering why it is so big. https://github.com/crossscardev/portfolio
Edit:
It seems that a large portion of the files in the chunks folder are named after programming languages, color themes, libraries, or other tools (Most of which I don't use in my project). Some of the filenames present:

angular-ts_CSCQpN2b.mjs
apache_ijTUt0Ee.mjs
asm_8rFmTrdo.mjs
nginx_DmbnMt-M.mjs
rust_D7urxq1K.mjs

